# return int value from dataStore preferences

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

I have an application where I'm saving `int` value using datastore preferences , when I get the value  , I execute the code and want to return that `int` value so that I can use it in different places in my code but could not figure it out , if anyone can help , thank you in advance

I tried to make a global member to assign that value and then return but since the value is returned asynchronously , it is crashing the app .

- This is my code

```
private fun setTextSize() : Int {
        val dataStore = requireContext().createDataStore("textSize")
        lifecycleScope.launch { 
            dataStore.data.collect { 
              val textSize =  it[Common.TEXT_SIZE_PREFERENCE] 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get the value directly you should use `runBlocking`.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
val textSize = runBlocking { dataStore.data.first() }[Common.TEXT_SIZE_PREFERENCE]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `suspend` modifier to your function and access it using `CoroutineScope` as

```
suspend fun setTextSize() = dataStore.data.firstOrNull()[Common.TEXT_SIZE_PREFERENCE] ?: -1
```

While accesing

```
lifeCycleScope.launch{
    val textSize = setTextSize()
}
```